# Создание глобальных переменных внутри функции

Tags: php

Можно ли как-то внутри функции создавать переменные, которые будут доступны после работы этой функции? Например, довольно часто мне приходится делать что-то подобное:

```
if (isset($_POST['something1']) and isset($_POST['something2']) and isset($_POST['something3'])) {

    //fix() - собственная функция от sql инъекций; $connection - переменная с подключением к бд
    $something1=fix($_POST['something1'], $connection);
    $something2=fix($_POST['something2'], $connection);
    $something3=fix($_POST['something3'], $connection);

    if (empty($something1) or empty($something2) or empty($something3)) exit();

} else exit();
```

А хочется как-то так:

```
$what_to_check=array('something1', 'something2', 'something3');
get_post_data($_POST, $what_to_check)
```

И на выходе имеем все переменные, которые уже проверены и т.п. Я начал писать функцию, но потом осознал, что при return я ведь не верну имя созданной перменной. Я верну только обработанное значение... Вот что вышло (без учёта массивов и т.п.)

```
function get_post_data($POST, $what_to_check) {

    global $connection;
    if (empty($POST) or empty($what_to_check) or empty($connection)) return FALSE;

    foreach ($what_to_check as $key => $value) {

        ${$value}=fix($value, $connection); //Надо как-то вернуть

    }

}
```

Пока писал пост этот, пришла идея: функцией этой просто обрабатывать переменные и заносить их во внутренний массив, который в конце работы функции возвращается. А потом уже отдельно вне функции каждому значению массива присвоить имя переменной из `$what_to_check`.

Какие есть идеи? Как быть?

Comment: используй mysqli и PDO и не загоняйся какой-то там непонятной костыльно-велосипедно-самопальной функцией обработки

Comment: а вообще созданием переменных по строковому имени, можно взглянуть на `$$` - Это когда значение переменной выступает именем другой переменной

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Проверка на sql инъекцию тут - это не самое главное. Главное вытаскивание нужных данных из массива $_POST, проверка их на не пустоту и т.п. А про $$ я знаю. Оно у меня и есть в функции. Но как из функции все эти переменные получить с возможностью использовать в остальном коде - вот вопрос. Или нужно не функцию использовать? Что тогда?

Comment: Вообще обычно `$$` используют для привязки переменных в шаблоне. А зачем такое делать для того, чтобы потом где-то использовать в других кусках кода?....где использовать их?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский. Я получаею переменные из $_POST. Проверяю, чтобы они существовали. Заодно обрезаю пробелы по краям, если это строки. И убираю опасные символы. После этого проверяю, чтобы переменные не были пустыми. Допустим, я получаю 10 штук. В итоге мне нужно каждую отдельно так проверить и т.п. И так не раз. Понимаете?

Comment: И в чем проблема проверить просто каждый элемент самого массива $_POST и затем его и вернуть отфильтрованный? Зачем эти пляски с созданием кучи переменных?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А мне потом что же 25 раз в коде ссылаться на объект массива?

Comment: Потом - когда? В каком коде? Еще раз, если это очистка для впихивания в БД - то распихивание по переменным - не нужно. В общем, нужно больше информации. Где ты там собрался их использовать, как, зачем и прочее. Без этого - все это смотрится каким-то непонятным желанием слепить какой-то костыль (хотя global $connection уже костыль)

Comment: я бы сделал так передал в функцию массив с тем что надо проверить, всё бы проверил и вернул бы чистый массив который уже можно запихать в БД без всякой опаски. Зачем создавать переменные непонятно. Или ещё такой вариант универсальная функция которая проверяет только одно значение и через цикл загоняем туда все значения по очереди и получаем ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Массив с описанием ошибок
    #ключи массива равны POST-переменным из html формы, а его 
    #значения - это названия html полей (т.е., ожидаемые данные)
    $what_to_check = [
        'name' => 'Имя',
        'age' => 'Возраст',
        'sex' => 'Пол'
    ];
    // Как-то отфильтровали массив $_POST
    # Обратите внимание, get_post_data() вызывается без
    # параметра, т.к. $_POST "виден" в теле функции
    $data = get_post_data();
    // Сравнили POST-данные с массивом $what_to_check
    $err = array_diff_key($what_to_check, $data);
    // Если данные не совпадают, выводим текст об ошибках
    if (!empty($err)) {
        echo 'Ошибка! Заполните пол'. (count($err) > 1 ? 'я' : 'е') .
            ': <hr /><b>'. join(', ', $err) .'</b>';
    } else {
        // Если ошибок нет, работаем с ранее отфильтрованными данными
        echo '<pre>'; var_dump($data); echo '</pre>';
    }
}


function get_post_data() {
    return array_filter(
        array_map(function($item) {
            return trim(htmlspecialchars($item));
        }, $_POST)
    );
}

?>

<form method="post">
    <p>Имя:<br />
    <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
    <p>Возраст:<br />
    <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
    <p>Пол:<br />
    <input type="text" name="sex" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Если надо передавать больше|меньше пост-параметров, то редактируйте соответственно ключи и значения вашего массива $what_to_check.

Comment: @Oboroten запостил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю добавить массив $values, куда вы будете собирать обработанные значения. Возвращаете соответственно этот массив. Если необходимо извлечь переменные из него, воспользуйтесь функцией [extract()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php).

```
function get_post_data($POST, $what_to_check) {
    $values = []; //Инициализируем массив, в который добавим обработанные значения

    $connection = DB::get_connection();
    if (empty($POST) or empty($what_to_check) or empty($connection)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    foreach ($what_to_check as $key => $value) {

        ${$value}=fix($value, $connection);
        $values[$value] = $$value; //Заносим в массив значения

    }

    return $values; //Возвращаем массив
}
```